How to properly implement Depth Buffering in Vulkan with C++?
Question on Implementing Depth Buffering in Vulkan for Layered Textures
I am making my way through the Vulkan Tutorial and have implemented everything up to and including Textures.  However, instead of implementing every example in the tutorial, line by line, I am trying to separate specific areas of execution into independent classes.  While I am setting up everything the tutorial asks for, and the code compiles and executes without error, the Depth Buffering is clearly not working and instead of rendering one square with a texture on top of another with a texture, it is rendering them together.  I am including the link to my github page where a the full code base is maintained.  A picture of the incorrectly rendered squares is shown below to highlight the incorrect behavior.  (Notice the aliased rendering in the area of overlap between the squares.)

Creating a Depth Manager
In this instance I am implementing depth buffering, with the following class titled DepthManager.  Below is the prototype in the graphics.hpp file and below that is the implementation which is in the graphics.cpp file.  I should say that I am also using the Vulkan Memory Allocator library to manage memory instead of the builtin allocator.
The prototype and implementation for DepthManager is shown below;
class DepthManager {
public:
    DepthManager(AllocatorManager& allocatorManager, VkDevice device, 
                 VkPhysicalDevice physicalDevice, VkExtent2D swapChainExtent);
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ~DepthManager();
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    VkImageView getDepthImageView() const { return depthImageView; }
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    void createDepthResources();
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    VkFormat findDepthFormat();
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    VkImageView getDepthImageView();
// ================================================================================
private:
    AllocatorManager& allocatorManager;
    VkDevice device;
    VkPhysicalDevice physicalDevice;
    VkExtent2D swapChainExtent;
    
    VkImage depthImage = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
    VmaAllocation depthImageMemory = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
    VkImageView depthImageView = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    bool hasStencilComponent(VkFormat format);
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

    VkFormat findSupportedFormat(const std::vector<VkFormat>& candidates, 
                                 VkImageTiling tiling, VkFormatFeatureFlags features);
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    void createImage(uint32_t width, uint32_t height, VkFormat format, 
                     VkImageTiling tiling, VkImageUsageFlags usage, 
                     VmaMemoryUsage memoryUsage, VkImage& image, 
                     VmaAllocation& imageMemory);
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    VkImageView createImageView(VkImage image, VkFormat format, VkImageAspectFlags aspectFlags);
};

The DepthManager implementation is shown below
DepthManager::DepthManager(AllocatorManager& allocatorManager, 
                           VkDevice device, 
                           VkPhysicalDevice physicalDevice, 
                           VkExtent2D swapChainExtent)
    : allocatorManager(allocatorManager),
      device(device),
      physicalDevice(physicalDevice),
      swapChainExtent(swapChainExtent) {
    createDepthResources();
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DepthManager::~DepthManager() {
    if (depthImageView != VK_NULL_HANDLE) {
        vkDestroyImageView(device, depthImageView, nullptr);
        depthImageView = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
    }

    if (depthImage != VK_NULL_HANDLE && depthImageMemory != VK_NULL_HANDLE) {
        vmaDestroyImage(allocatorManager.getAllocator(), depthImage, depthImageMemory);
        depthImage = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
        depthImageMemory = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
    }
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void DepthManager::createDepthResources() {
    VkFormat depthFormat = findDepthFormat();

    // Create depth image and verify initialization
    createImage(swapChainExtent.width, swapChainExtent.height, depthFormat, 
                VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL, VK_IMAGE_USAGE_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_BIT, 
                VMA_MEMORY_USAGE_GPU_ONLY, depthImage, depthImageMemory);
    
    // Check if depthImage and depthImageMemory are valid
    if (depthImage == VK_NULL_HANDLE || depthImageMemory == VK_NULL_HANDLE) {
        throw std::runtime_error("DepthManager: Failed to initialize depth image or memory allocation.");
    }

    // Create depth image view and verify initialization
    depthImageView = createImageView(depthImage, depthFormat, VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_DEPTH_BIT);

    // Check if depthImageView is valid
    if (depthImageView == VK_NULL_HANDLE) {
        throw std::runtime_error("DepthManager: Failed to initialize depth image view.");
    }
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

VkFormat DepthManager::findDepthFormat() {
    // Define the list of depth formats to check in order of preference
    std::vector<VkFormat> depthFormats = {
        VK_FORMAT_D32_SFLOAT, 
        VK_FORMAT_D32_SFLOAT_S8_UINT, 
        VK_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT
    };

    // Loop through each candidate format and check for support
    for (VkFormat format : depthFormats) {
        VkFormatProperties props;
        vkGetPhysicalDeviceFormatProperties(physicalDevice, format, &props);

        // Check if this format supports optimal tiling for depth-stencil attachment
        if (props.optimalTilingFeatures & VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_BIT) {
            return format;
        }
    }

    throw std::runtime_error("failed to find supported depth format!");
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

VkImageView DepthManager::getDepthImageView() {
    return depthImageView;
}
// ================================================================================

bool DepthManager::hasStencilComponent(VkFormat format) {
    return format == VK_FORMAT_D32_SFLOAT_S8_UINT || format == VK_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

VkFormat DepthManager::findSupportedFormat(const std::vector<VkFormat>& candidates, 
                                           VkImageTiling tiling, VkFormatFeatureFlags features) {
    for (VkFormat format : candidates) {
        VkFormatProperties props;
        vkGetPhysicalDeviceFormatProperties(physicalDevice, format, &props);

        if (tiling == VK_IMAGE_TILING_LINEAR && (props.linearTilingFeatures & features) == features) {
            return format;
        } else if (tiling == VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL && (props.optimalTilingFeatures & features) == features) {
            return format;
        }
    }

    throw std::runtime_error("failed to find supported format!");
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void DepthManager::createImage(uint32_t width, uint32_t height, VkFormat format, 
                               VkImageTiling tiling, VkImageUsageFlags usage, 
                               VmaMemoryUsage memoryUsage, VkImage& image, 
                               VmaAllocation& imageMemory) {
    VkImageCreateInfo imageInfo{};
    imageInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO;
    imageInfo.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
    imageInfo.extent.width = width;
    imageInfo.extent.height = height;
    imageInfo.extent.depth = 1;
    imageInfo.mipLevels = 1;
    imageInfo.arrayLayers = 1;
    imageInfo.format = format;
    imageInfo.tiling = tiling;
    imageInfo.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    imageInfo.usage = usage;
    imageInfo.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    imageInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;

    VmaAllocationCreateInfo allocInfo{};
    allocInfo.usage = memoryUsage;

    if (vmaCreateImage(allocatorManager.getAllocator(), &imageInfo, &allocInfo, &image, &imageMemory, nullptr) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create image!");
    }
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

VkImageView DepthManager::createImageView(VkImage image, VkFormat format, 
                                          VkImageAspectFlags aspectFlags) {
    VkImageViewCreateInfo viewInfo{};
    viewInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_CREATE_INFO;
    viewInfo.image = image;
    viewInfo.viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D;
    viewInfo.format = format;
    viewInfo.subresourceRange.aspectMask = aspectFlags;
    viewInfo.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
    viewInfo.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
    viewInfo.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    viewInfo.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;

    VkImageView imageView;
    if (vkCreateImageView(device, &viewInfo, nullptr, &imageView) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create texture image view!");
    }

    return imageView;
}

Managing Depth in the Graphics Pipeline
The tutorial also requires that I update the createRenderPass and createFrameBuffer methods which are part of the graphics pipeline, For completeness I am showing those methods with the updates below.
void GraphicsPipeline::createRenderPass(VkFormat swapChainImageFormat) {
    VkAttachmentDescription colorAttachment{};
    colorAttachment.format = swapChainImageFormat;
    colorAttachment.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    colorAttachment.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
    colorAttachment.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
    colorAttachment.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
    colorAttachment.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    colorAttachment.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    colorAttachment.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR;

    VkAttachmentDescription depthAttachment{};
    depthAttachment.format = depthManager.findDepthFormat();
    depthAttachment.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    depthAttachment.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
    depthAttachment.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    depthAttachment.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
    depthAttachment.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    depthAttachment.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    depthAttachment.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

    VkAttachmentReference colorAttachmentRef{};
    colorAttachmentRef.attachment = 0;
    colorAttachmentRef.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

    VkAttachmentReference depthAttachmentRef{};
    depthAttachmentRef.attachment = 1;
    depthAttachmentRef.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

    VkSubpassDescription subpass{};
    subpass.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
    subpass.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
    subpass.pColorAttachments = &colorAttachmentRef;
    subpass.pDepthStencilAttachment = &depthAttachmentRef;

    VkSubpassDependency dependency{};
    dependency.srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
    dependency.dstSubpass = 0;
    dependency.srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT | VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_EARLY_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT;
    dependency.srcAccessMask = 0;
    dependency.dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT | VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_EARLY_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT;
    dependency.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT | VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;

    // Correct the attachments array and count
    std::array<VkAttachmentDescription, 2> attachments = {colorAttachment, depthAttachment};

    VkRenderPassCreateInfo renderPassInfo{};
    renderPassInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_CREATE_INFO;
    renderPassInfo.attachmentCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(attachments.size());  // Set to 2
    renderPassInfo.pAttachments = attachments.data();  // Point to both color and depth attachments
    renderPassInfo.subpassCount = 1;
    renderPassInfo.pSubpasses = &subpass;
    renderPassInfo.dependencyCount = 1;
    renderPassInfo.pDependencies = &dependency;

    if (vkCreateRenderPass(device, &renderPassInfo, nullptr, &renderPass) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create render pass!");
    }
}

void GraphicsPipeline::createFrameBuffers(const std::vector<VkImageView>& swapChainImageViews, 
                                          VkExtent2D swapChainExtent) {
    // Verify depthImageView is initialized
    VkImageView depthImageView = depthManager.getDepthImageView();
    if (depthImageView == VK_NULL_HANDLE) {
        throw std::runtime_error("DepthManager depthImageView is not initialized.");
    }
    framebuffers.resize(swapChainImageViews.size());

    for (size_t i = 0; i < swapChainImageViews.size(); i++) {
            std::array<VkImageView, 2> attachments = {
                swapChainImageViews[i],
                depthImageView
            };

        VkFramebufferCreateInfo framebufferInfo{};
        framebufferInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_FRAMEBUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
        framebufferInfo.renderPass = renderPass;
        framebufferInfo.attachmentCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(attachments.size());
        framebufferInfo.pAttachments = attachments.data();
        framebufferInfo.width = swapChainExtent.width;
        framebufferInfo.height = swapChainExtent.height;
        framebufferInfo.layers = 1;

        if (vkCreateFramebuffer(device, &framebufferInfo, nullptr, &framebuffers[i]) != VK_SUCCESS) {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to create framebuffer!");
        }
    }
}

Invoking the Vulkan Instance with Depth Buffering
The problem may be related to the order in which I am instantiating classes, so for completeness I am also showing the constructor below for the VulkanApplication class where the entire application is organized.  The main function is shown below.
GLFWwindow* create_window(uint32_t h, uint32_t w, const std::string& screen_title, bool full_screen) {
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("GLFW Initialization Failed!\n");
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE);

    GLFWmonitor* monitor = full_screen ? glfwGetPrimaryMonitor() : nullptr;

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(w, h, screen_title.c_str(), monitor, nullptr);

    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        throw std::runtime_error("GLFW Instantiation failed!\n");
    }
    return window;
}
// ================================================================================
// ================================================================================ 


// Begin code
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    // Define vertices for two connected triangles  
    const std::vector<Vertex> vertices = {
        // First square, slightly offset along the x-axis and closer along the z-axis
        {{-0.4f, -0.4f, -0.25f}, {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}, {1.0f, 0.0f}},
        {{0.4f, -0.4f, -0.25f}, {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}},
        {{0.4f, 0.4f, -0.25f}, {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}, {0.0f, 1.0f}},
        {{-0.4f, 0.4f, -0.25f}, {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}, {1.0f, 1.0f}},

        // Second square, further along z-axis and offset along x-axis
        {{-0.5f + 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.75f}, {1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f}, {1.0f, 0.0f}},
        {{0.5f + 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.75f}, {0.5f, 1.0f, 0.5f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}},
        {{0.5f + 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.75f}, {0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f}, {0.0f, 1.0f}},
        {{-0.5f + 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.75f}, {0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f}, {1.0f, 1.0f}}
    };
    const std::vector<uint16_t> indices = {
        0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0,
        4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 4
    };
    
    // Call Application 
    try {
        GLFWwindow* window = create_window(1050, 1200, "Vulkan Application", false);
        VulkanApplication triangle(window, vertices, indices);

        triangle.run();

         // Clean up the GLFW window
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);

        // Terminate GLFW and clean up resources
        glfwTerminate();
    } catch(const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() <<  "\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

The main function instantiates the VulkanApplication class shown below.
VulkanApplication::VulkanApplication(GLFWwindow* window, 
                                     const std::vector<Vertex>& vertices,
                                     const std::vector<uint16_t>& indices)
    : windowInstance(std::move(window)),
      vertices(vertices),
      indices(indices){
    // Instantiate related classes
    glfwSetWindowUserPointer(windowInstance, this);

    validationLayers = std::make_unique<ValidationLayers>();
    vulkanInstanceCreator = std::make_unique<VulkanInstance>(this->windowInstance, 
                                                             *validationLayers.get());
    vulkanPhysicalDevice = std::make_unique<VulkanPhysicalDevice>(*this->vulkanInstanceCreator->getInstance(),
                                                                  this->vulkanInstanceCreator->getSurface());
    vulkanLogicalDevice = std::make_unique<VulkanLogicalDevice>(vulkanPhysicalDevice->getDevice(),
                                                                validationLayers->getValidationLayers(),
                                                                vulkanInstanceCreator->getSurface(),
                                                                deviceExtensions);
    allocatorManager = std::make_unique<AllocatorManager>(
        vulkanPhysicalDevice->getDevice(),
        vulkanLogicalDevice->getDevice(),
        *vulkanInstanceCreator->getInstance());

    swapChain = std::make_unique<SwapChain>(vulkanLogicalDevice->getDevice(),
                                            vulkanInstanceCreator->getSurface(),
                                            vulkanPhysicalDevice->getDevice(),
                                            this->windowInstance);
    depthManager = std::make_unique<DepthManager>(
        *allocatorManager,                              // Dereference unique_ptr
        vulkanLogicalDevice->getDevice(),
        vulkanPhysicalDevice->getDevice(),
        swapChain->getSwapChainExtent()
    );
    //depthManager->createDepthResources();
    commandBufferManager = std::make_unique<CommandBufferManager>(vulkanLogicalDevice->getDevice(),
                                                                  indices,
                                                                  vulkanPhysicalDevice->getDevice(),
                                                                  vulkanInstanceCreator->getSurface());
    samplerManager = std::make_unique<SamplerManager>(
            vulkanLogicalDevice->getDevice(),
            vulkanPhysicalDevice->getDevice()
    );
    samplerManager->createSampler("default");
    textureManager = std::make_unique<TextureManager>(
        *allocatorManager,                              // Dereference unique_ptr
        vulkanLogicalDevice->getDevice(),
        vulkanPhysicalDevice->getDevice(),
        *commandBufferManager,                          // Dereference unique_ptr
        vulkanLogicalDevice->getGraphicsQueue(),
        "../../../data/texture.jpg",
        *samplerManager
    );
    bufferManager = std::make_unique<BufferManager>(vertices,
                                                    indices,
                                                    *allocatorManager,
                                                    *commandBufferManager.get(),
                                                    vulkanLogicalDevice->getGraphicsQueue());
    descriptorManager = std::make_unique<DescriptorManager>(vulkanLogicalDevice->getDevice());
    descriptorManager->createDescriptorSets(bufferManager->getUniformBuffers(),
                                            textureManager->getTextureImageView(),
                                            samplerManager->getSampler("default"));
    graphicsPipeline = std::make_unique<GraphicsPipeline>(vulkanLogicalDevice->getDevice(),
                                                          *swapChain.get(),
                                                          *commandBufferManager.get(),
                                                          *bufferManager.get(),
                                                          *descriptorManager.get(),
                                                          indices,
                                                          vulkanPhysicalDevice->getDevice(),
                                                          std::string("../../shaders/shader.vert.spv"),
                                                          std::string("../../shaders/shader.frag.spv"),
                                                          *depthManager);
    graphicsPipeline->createFrameBuffers(swapChain->getSwapChainImageViews(), 
                                         swapChain->getSwapChainExtent());
    graphicsQueue = this->vulkanLogicalDevice->getGraphicsQueue();
    presentQueue = this->vulkanLogicalDevice->getPresentQueue();
}

As I said before, the application works, it is just not properly implementing DepthBuffering between the two squares, and I am not sure why! I think the issue is either in how teh DepthBuffer`` class is written, or how it is used to support the createRenderPassorcreateFrameBufferfunctions, but is may also be in how it is called in theVulkanApplication` constructor, so I am sharing those implementations as well.  Essentially, until someone who knows better than I can point out the error, I am at a dead stop and would appreciate any help that I can get.  Please feel free to sift through the gitub address shown at the top if you think the issue resides somewhere else.

It took a bit to debug something that was so simple, but the issue was caused by my Vertex class.  The getAttributeDescriptons() function was set to receive 2D information and not 3D information.  The correct function is shown below.
static std::array<VkVertexInputAttributeDescription, 3> getAttributeDescriptions() {
        std::array<VkVertexInputAttributeDescription, 3> attributeDescriptions{};

        attributeDescriptions[0].binding = 0;
        attributeDescriptions[0].location = 0;
        attributeDescriptions[0].format = VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32_SFLOAT;
        attributeDescriptions[0].offset = offsetof(Vertex, pos);

        attributeDescriptions[1].binding = 0;
        attributeDescriptions[1].location = 1;
        attributeDescriptions[1].format = VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32_SFLOAT;
        attributeDescriptions[1].offset = offsetof(Vertex, color);

        attributeDescriptions[2].binding = 0;
        attributeDescriptions[2].location = 2;
        attributeDescriptions[2].format = VK_FORMAT_R32G32_SFLOAT;
        attributeDescriptions[2].offset = offsetof(Vertex, texCoord);

        return attributeDescriptions;
    }

